# compiling ncmpcpp with cygwin in windows

Tags: c++, boost, build, compilation, cygwin

So I'm trying to compile ncmpcpp using cygwin. I'm running windows 7, so you can understand the difficulty I'm having. Whenever I ./configure, I get an error message:
"checking for main in -lboost_filesystem-mt... no
configure: error: no boost.filesystem library found"
I have every required and optional library in my cygwin/(username)/home/ncmpcpp-0.6 folder. I have compiled everything I can, or know how to compile. I don't really understand what the boost.filesystem is, and I don't know how to compile or build it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Configure script uses BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX, which is by default set to "-mt". It's possible you have boost libraries compiled in a way so that they don't have it. In this case you need to invoke `$ BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=<suffix> ./configure`, and `<suffix>` in most cases would be empty.

Comment: That fixed my original problem, but now i get:
"checking for libmpdclient... no
configure: error: libmpdclient >= 2.8 is required!"
and i have libmpdclient and i've configured it, however it won't make. Whenever i try it gives me this: 
doc/doxygen.conf
make[1]: execvp: doc/doxygen.conf: Permission denied
Makefile:1372: recipe for target 'doc/api/html/index.html' failed
make[1]: *** [doc/api/html/index.html] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/ncmpcpp-0.6/libmpdclient-2.8'
Makefile:437: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
is there a make invocation i need to use?

Comment: You got permission denied on doc/doxygen.conf, I guess you can try fixing that?